# Cokernel of Morphism of Free Sheaves with Infinite Rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, coherent-sheaves

From exercise II.5.4 of Hartshorne, we know that $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ of Noetherian scheme $X$ is coherent if and only if it is cokernel of morphism of free sheaves with finite rank. What is example of cokernel of free sheaves with infinite rank that is not coherent?

Comment: $\mathrm{Coker}(0 \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: @Sasha thank you